# Enhanced link attribution in Google Analytics In-page Analytics not working

Tags: google-analytics

Has anyone been able to use and see the Enhanced Link Attribution data in the In-Page Analytics interface of Google Analytics as per this document?

http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2558867

I've implemented this plugin and call and I can see the data being transferred to GA in my __utm.gif call however when viewing the In-page Analytics of the site, there is no difference. I still see the clicks being shown in an aggregated standard form.

I'm curious if there is a piece missing and I need to enable some Advanced Segment filters or something to view the information.

There is a thread on Google Groups where people shared similar experience with the implementation and my observations are the same:

http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!searchin/analytics/enhanced$20link$20attribution/analytics/-FuKG8ARAPY/t-crCmrGEHsJ

Any help or insight would be highly appreciated! Google seems to be on mute as usual.

Comment: Having the same problem on multiple websites. Did you solve it?

Comment: I seem to have... I had to manually put a unique 'id' attribute to each <a> tag on each page that I wanted to distinguish.

I picked a naming convention that allowed me to have unique ID's and not to worry about duplicity. In my site template, all header links use for example <a href="/" id="header-home">Home</a>, footer in a similar way <a href="/" id="footer-home">Homepage</a>. Links in the body of page are similarly <a href="/" id="body-home">go to homepage</a>.

This has made the percentage in GA show different values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the problem, I had to manually put a unique 'id' attribute to each link  tag pointing to the same URL that I wanted to distinguish. The scope is the page so you don't need to worry if the same IDs repeat on different pages, they just need to be unique per page.

I used a naming convention that allowed me to have unique IDs and not to worry about duplicity, unless there were two links to the same URL within a section (in my header I have the logo and the home navigation link go to the same URL).

For example, in my site template, all header links use id="header-...", all links in the footer use id="footer-...", and all links in the body of the page use id="body-...".

Example:

`<a href="/" id="header-home">Home</a>
<a href="/" id="header-logo"><img src="/logo.gif" alt="logo" /></a>
<a href="/" id="body-home">go to homepage</a>
<a href="/" id="footer-home">Homepage</a>`

This has made the percentage in GA show different values for the same URL, which solved the problem. Nothing else I tried in the settings, or initializing the enhanced attribution plugin, did not work.

Answer (score -1):

This was just announced:
http://analytics.blogspot.co.il/2012/11/announcing-enhanced-link-attribution.html

You'll need to enable enhanced link attribution in the web property settings tab (within the Admin section), which is rolling out - you may see it only in a few days/weeks.

Comment: Sorry to pick up on this after a delay... This setting was done as my first step. The help directed me to install the plugin but the distinction in attribution was not picking it up anyways.

Answer (score -1):

First : Go to Analytics. Click "Admin" in the top right for the selected web property. Property settings tab > In-Page Analytics heading > Use enhanced link attribution = Tick checkbox.

You might also want to narrow down the date window to the last few days when looking at the data (after allowing 24 hours for it to come in). If you don't do this, the link-attributed data might get diluted in the standard "last 30 days" window.

Comment: Sorry to pick up on this after a delay... This setting was done as my first step. The help directed me to install the plugin but the distinction in attribution was not picking it up anyways.